# Question about webpart properties

Tags: web-part, properties, custom-web-part-property

How can I access a custom property in my webpart?

I have a page that contains webparts, which contains multiple instances of the same custom webpart. I wanted to use the `.webpart` file to add my own custom property like :

```
<property name="CustomProperty" type="string">value</property>
```

so I can treat each webpart according to this value.

I can't seems to get hold of this property. I can access title , description etc. but not my property.

I managed to create a custom property which I can handle while editing the webpart at runtime, but I would like to set it once in the `.webpart` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as alex stated,

Also you need to make sure your actualy putting in the values first ;), You need a constant with a value or "" , then the getter setter with that const varible to get and set, you finaly need to add a constructor that contains the private varibles that pass the const to the private:

create your base class:

add const:

```
//this is your default string
const string c_MyStringDefault = "Sample String";
```

add private string:

```
//this will be used internaly through the constructor
private string _myString;
```

add constructor:

```
   // Constructor
   public  CustomPropertyWebPart()
   {
    // Initialize private variables.
    _myString = c_MyStringDefault;
   }
```

add the get/set method

```
    // Creates a custom property that is a string.
    // This property will be displayed as a text box in the
    // property pane.

    // Create a custom category in the property sheet.
    [Category("Custom Properties")]
    // Assign the default value.
    [DefaultValue(c_MyStringDefault)]
    // Property is available in both Personalization
    // and Customization mode.
    [WebPartStorage(Storage.Personal)]
    // The caption that appears in the property sheet.
    [FriendlyNameAttribute("Custom String")]
    // The tool tip that appears when pausing the mouse pointer over
    // the friendly name in the property pane.
    [Description("Type a string value.")]
    // Display the property in the property pane.
    [Browsable(true)]
    [XmlElement(ElementName="MyString")]
    // The accessor for this property.
    public string MyString
    {
        get
        {
            return _myString;
        }
        set
        {
            _myString = value;
        }
    }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd584174(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: no probs happy to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

In your custom web part create a public property:

```
[Browsable(false)]
public string Value { get; set; }
```

Then you can access the public property and set it in your CustomWebpart.webpart file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<webParts>
  <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
    <metaData>
      <type name="CustomWebpart, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" />
      <importErrorMessage>$Resources:core,ImportErrorMessage;</importErrorMessage>
    </metaData>
    <data>
      <properties>
        <property name="Title" type="string">myWebpart</property>
        <property name="Description" type="string">My Visual WebPart</property>
        <property name="Value" type="string">your value</property>
      </properties>
    </data>
  </webPart>
</webParts>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I did as suggested but for some reason I get null for this property even that I set value in it. any suggestions ?

Comment: Hi Ronen, try adding the [Browsable(false)] attribute to your property, I think it will solve your problem.
See an updated code example above.